# Issue with VPN static routing, on windows 10

Tags: windows, vpn, routing

I want to be able to connect to remote server over `l2tp` VPN, but want to stay online throw my LAN connection `192.168.0.1/24`.

The issue on Windows 10, I have the main inet connection in `192.168.0.1/24` network, also configured a static routes, 1) has the `metric=5`, and the VPN route has the lower `metric = 10`, (ps/ routing table shown in pic attached) when I put on the VPN setting also the main gw for the remote network is switched ON.

However when the VPN connected I have the ping for it, but doesn't have a route to for the local network and inet.

[image: ss]

Who knows how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The 0.0.0.0 is the default route for VPN traffic to go out.

All VPN traffic is sent out from this default route.

It does not show the default route to which specific address, such as a route to the local network or inet.